# Ruby scripting - how to keep track of configurations

Tags: ruby

I am writing a system script in Ruby.
I'm using the classic gem structure: `lib`, `bin`, `spec` for RSpec.

I want to build a configurable script: I want to be able to provide options like `--set-stuff` and alike. A perfect example is:

```
git config --global user.name "Andrea"
```

which writes the given information out to a file, in order to be able to retrieve this information later.

How can I do this in a clean way?
I'd rather not use the environment variable solution: I know I could just set an env variable to point to a configuration file, but then I'd have to save this env variable in, say, `.bashrc`. Then again, how do I deal with `zsh`? Or how do I deal with people (like me) who keep their `.bashrc`s super-neat or even have a separate `.env-variables` file in their system?

Comment: “I want to be able to provide options like --set-stuff and alike” seems mostly unrelated to having configuration files, which is what the rest of the question is about. Not really clear what you’re asking.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall I wasn't clear, I'm sorry. Check my comment to the above answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just stick the configuration into a Hash and serialize it into a file in the user's home directory as YAML or JSON...

Comment: This seems like the opposite of "clean" :). What if I want the user to be able to move this configuration file? I'm not too eager to force him to symlink it or similar solutions.

Comment: The usual solution is to provide a command-line option to point at a different configuration file location than the default.  Also, you can do what some tools do and look for the configuration file starting with the current working directory, which makes it easy to override settings on a per-project basis.